# Grep quotation mark inside quotation mark

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

example.txt

```
alias znm="base64"
alias asu="sed 's/.\{4\}/&™/g'"
alias mmk="sed 's/\(.\{4\}\)\™/\1/g'"
alias mmk="sed 's/\(.\{8\}\)\™/\1/g'"
```

Desired output:

```
alias asu="sed 's/.\{4\}/&™/g'"
```

But it's get error when i tried this

```
grep -wo "alias asu="sed 's/.\{4\}/&™/g'"" example.txt
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Why not just `grep asu example.txt` or `awk 'NR==2' example.txt`?

Comment: I need the whole text in that line | and the line is random not always at the second line

Comment: The first command with `grep` will give you that entire line which is your desired output. Have you tried using it?

Comment: @NasirRiley i know, but i need to grep the whole sentence

Comment: No, you don't. The command that I just gave you returns the output that you want. You are complicating something that's very simple.

Comment: @NasirRiley It would output whatever is on the second line, no matter what that was. I'm imagining that they want to test whether the particular alias is in the file (with an exact alias definition).

Comment: @Kusalananda I understand that but the `grep` command gives the expected output as they confirmed. If they wanted that exact alias then that should have been specified in the question. With the way that it's written, that information is being obfuscated.

Comment: @NasirRiley I think that it's pretty clear that they wanted the exact alias given the `grep` command that they tried to use.

Comment: @Kusalananda Except when it's not. It's very often that people ask questions because they are stuck using an unnecessarily complex command when a simpler one works much better. Maybe it's not this question, but there have been plenty of times where someone tried a complex `grep` or `sed` command to print a string when the same can be done more easily with `awk`. I'm only saying that it would have helped to make it clear in the question as to what exactly is needed so that this doesn't occur.

Comment: @NasirRiley In this case, I'd say it's clear. You are perfectly correct in saying that people _often_ use far too complicated workflows for doing simple things (often due to not knowing the correct syntax of the shell or what tools may or may not do), but this particular question does not strike me as being one of those instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Fx -f /dev/stdin example.txt <<'PATTERN'
alias asu="sed 's/.\{4\}/&™/g'"
PATTERN
```

This avoids the issues that you're having with the quotes and regular expression characters and passes the pattern as is into `grep` on standard input.  The `grep` utility reads the pattern from standard input because we've asked it, with `-f /dev/stdin`, to do that (on Android, you may instead use `-f /dev/fd/0`).

The `-F` uses the pattern as a string instead of as a regular expression, and `-x` ensures that we only matches lines that matches the pattern completely (as if the pattern was anchored to both start and finish of the line).

Using this as a test for whether that particular alias is in the file:

```sh
if grep -q -Fx -f /dev/stdin example.txt; then
    echo the alias is there
else
    echo the alias is not there
fi <<'PATTERN'
alias asu="sed 's/.\{4\}/&™/g'"
PATTERN
```

---

Your command,

```
grep -wo "alias asu="sed 's/.\{4\}/&™/g'"" example.txt
```

is really calling `grep` with a pattern and *two* filenames:

- `"alias asu="sed` is the pattern (really, a regular expression, as you don't use `-F`).
- `'s/.\{4\}/&™/g'""` is the first filename since the shell will break the string on the unquoted space.
- `example.txt` is the second filename.

You could obviously make sure to quote all special characters and quotes, but using a here-document is slightly easier as you don't have to modify the pattern at all.

Comment: grep: /dev/stdin: No such file or directory  |  It's not work, am i doing it wrong

Comment: @IISomeOneII Oh, that's interesting! Are you on an AIX system? What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: Linux localhost 3.18.31-perf-g653a83a #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 28 10:05:53 WIB 2019 aarch64 Android

Comment: @IISomeOneII Hmmm... Could you try with `/proc/self/fd/0` in place of `/dev/stdin`? I'm not aware of how Linux works on Android devices. I'm testing this on Ubuntu Linux and OpenBSD, and both provides `/dev/stdin`. The other possibility is that you mistyped something.

Comment: @IISomeOneII Yes, `/dev/fd/0` or `/proc/self/fd/0` should work on Android.

Comment: Thx @Kusalananda, in the past you helped me a lot, I really appreciate your help, really really thx 